# How to install ReviewBoard under Nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, review-board

Sorry for my poor english, I'm french... no one is perfect.

I'm trying to install ReviewBoard under Nginx (LEMP with Debian Wheezy, Nginx 1.4.5, MySQL 14.14, PHP 5.4.4). My python installation use Python 2.7.3, easy_install 0.6.24dev-r0, pip 1.1, virtualenv 1.11.4 and gunicorn 18.0.

I succeeded to install all that stuff and create a reviewboard site but I fail to access the reviewboard site from a browser.

I know that reviewboard recommends Apache but also that is possible to install it on Nginx. I can't find any step-by-step tutorial except many links to http: / /rramsden.ca/blog/2011/09/26/nginx-reviewboard/ but this link is dead. Does anyone know another link ?

My Nginx conf is:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name review.unskontrollables.org;
    root /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs;

    # Error handlers
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /errordocs/500.html;

    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    # Alias static media requests to filesystem
    location /media {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/media;
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/static;
    }
    location /errordocs {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/errordocs;
    }
    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png;
    }
    #~ location /admin/media/ {
        #~ # this changes depending on your python version
        #~ root /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib;
    #~ }

    location / {
        #alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/reviewboard.wsgi;
        #root /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/reviewboard.wsgi/;
        #proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }

    # Prevent the server from processing or allowing the rendering of
    # certain file types.
    location /media/uploaded {
        types {
            text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phps .asp .pl .py .fcgi .cgi .phtml .phtm .pht .jsp .sh .rb;
        }
    }
}
```

To launch the WSGI server, I use:

```
root@jotunn:~# source /opt/reviewboard/rbenv/bin/activate
(rbenv)root@jotunn:~# rb-site manage /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/ runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.10, using settings 'reviewboard.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

If I try to access

```
http://review.unskontrollables.org/
```

I'm redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/
```

and the console output is:

```
/opt/reviewboard/rbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/list_detail.py:10: DeprecationWarning: Function-based generic views have been deprecated; use class-based views instead.
  DeprecationWarning
/opt/reviewboard/rbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py:75: DeprecationWarning: The ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX setting has been removed; use STATIC_URL instead.
  "use STATIC_URL instead.", DeprecationWarning)
/opt/reviewboard/rbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/simple.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Function-based generic views have been deprecated; use class-based views instead.
  DeprecationWarning
[14/Mar/2014 16:59:50] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 0
```

Does any one has an idea ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I found a solution based on the following tutorial
https://github.com/shuge/man/blob/master/sa/review/reviewboard/reviewboard-quick-install-guide.md
The missing link to the config file rb.m.com.conf point this file: https://github.com/shuge/man/blob/master/sa/review/reviewboard/rb.m.com.conf

With that data, I've just add flup (fastcgi python module) and changed my conf to the following:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name review.unskontrollables.org;
    root /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs;

    # Error handlers
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /errordocs/500.html;

    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    # Alias static media requests to filesystem
    location /media {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/media;
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/static;
    }
    location /errordocs {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/errordocs;
    }
    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/review.unskontrollables.org/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png;
    }
    #~ location /admin/media/ {
        #~ # this changes depending on your python version
        #~ root /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib;
    #~ }

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;      
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;      
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;      
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;      
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;      
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;      
        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;      
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off; 
    }

    # Prevent the server from processing or allowing the rendering of
    # certain file types.
    location /media/uploaded {
        types {
            text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phps .asp .pl .py .fcgi .cgi .phtml .phtm .pht .jsp .sh .rb;
        }
    }
}
```

After that nginx is restarted, everything works fine.

Comment: in this review board, does it have a settings to set the URL it should be running on ? I believe this is a redirection from the app it self

Comment: Thanks for your help but it wasn't a review board configuration issue. As I explained in my edit (see above), it is the proxy configuration that was false. With fastcgi, everything is fine.

Comment: Both links to github are removed: `Repository unavailable due to DMCA takedown.`